# How to UNION multiple databases as one source

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 40+ databases (linked servers) in my SSMS connection, each has the same schema, tables, columns but with unique data for each individual location. I'm looking for the best way to UNION them all together into a VIEW or Alias that would allow me to assign and ID based on the database/location and have a single source to query against essentially for future cross reference.

For example, I would like to be able to query against a single common table between the databases that has columns [order], [item], [amount] and add an additional column [location] based on the database the data is coming from within the query. Such as:

```
SELECT *
FROM [UnionTableSource]
```

Which shows results such as

```
Location | Order | Item | Amount
1        | 1234  | 567  | $500
2        | 1234  | 529  | $125
3        | 1279  | 529  | $125
3        | 1234  | 789  | $100
```

Comment: Create a view with the columns you need. I hope you are patient as querying 40 remote databases at a time is not likely going to perform very well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a view that UNIONs the tables together, for example:

```
CREATE VIEW AllOrders
AS

SELECT 1 AS Location, Order, Item, Amount FROM [Server1].[Database].dbo.Orders
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS Location, Order, Item, Amount FROM [Server2].[Database].dbo.Orders
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS Location, Order, Item, Amount FROM [Server3].[Database].dbo.Orders
--etc...
```

And you can query it as you would any view:

```
SELECT * 
FROM AllOrders 
WHERE Location = 2
```

Be aware that performance might be an issue if you have 40 databases in this list, though it may even perform quite well if the tables are extremely large as the workload is split across servers. This is basically poor-man's partitioning.

Comment: I would make this UNION ALL to avoid having to check for duplicates. :)

Comment: It will remove dupes which in this case is an added performance hit that isn't needed. UNION ALL returns all rows and doesn't check for dupes.

Comment: Second that, would definitely recommend changing the answer to use UNION ALL.

Comment: Yeah I'll go with UNION ALL since even if there shouldn't be duplicates and even if there were between databases I need to see each between locations. Thanks for the quick solution

Comment: @SeanLange Yeah you're right - I don't spend enough time in SQL Server these day, it's hard to remember the little things :/